# What's the average number of bots or spiders to visit a webpage per day?

Tags: seo, web-crawler, bots

I'm trying to get a rough estimate of how many of my page views are from bots. What's typical for the number of page views that bots and search spiders account for for an average SEO'd webpage?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple answer since the number of bots really depends on how widely exposed your site is. Google bases its crawl on how many pages link to yours, more is better.

For a reasonably visible site, I'd expect anywhere from 10 to 15 crawlers, each crawling your site monthly, and at most, weekly.